# CCPhysicsjoint not keeping the 2 bodies intact

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I want to add a particle body(say `Fire`) before another physics body(the `arrow`).
So, i am using the `spring joint` to keep them joined with stiffness around 20000, but still its starting the correct way and the particle-body swings away form the arrow. Here's my code:

`fire part`

```
CCParticleSystem *explosion= [CCParticleSystem particleWithFile:@"bomb.plist"];
explosion.position = ccpAdd(projectilePos, ccp(16,0));
explosion.physicsBody.mass=1.0;
explosion.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:16.0    andCenter:explosion.anchorPointInPoints];
explosion.physicsBody.type=CCPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic;
explosion.physicsBody.affectedByGravity=FALSE; 
explosion.physicsBody.allowsRotation=FALSE;  //so that fire flames go upwards only, and not rotate
[physicsWorld addChild:explosion];
explosion.physicsBody.collisionMask=@[];
```

`arrow part`

```
CCSprite *tempSprite;
tempSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"arrow3@2x.png"];
[tempSprite setScale:0.05];
[tempSprite setScaleY:0.15];
tempSprite.rotation=rotation;
tempSprite.position=dummyBow.position;
tempSprite.name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%d",[lifeOfSprite[1] objectForKey:@"name"],[[lifeOfSprite[1] objectForKey:@"life"] intValue]];
tempSprite.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, tempSprite.contentSize} cornerRadius:0]; // 1
tempSprite.physicsBody.collisionGroup = @"playerGroup";
tempSprite.physicsBody.collisionType  = @"projectileCollision";
[physicsWorld addChild:tempSprite z:0];
projectile.physicsBody.mass=100;
```

`now the joint part`

```
[CCPhysicsJoint connectedSpringJointWithBodyA:playerBomb.physicsBody bodyB:projectile.physicsBody anchorA:ccp(1,1) anchorB:ccp(600,0) restLength:0.f stiffness:20000.f damping:60.f];
```

[image: image loading]![arrow with fire]
[image]
(debugDraw)
the fire should come at the front, but swings back from front by spring effect

Can anyone tell where's the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try other method `connectedDistanceJointWithBodyA`.

Comment: A small change in the joint part..

[CCPhysicsJoint connectedSpringJointWithBodyA:explosion.physicsBody bodyB:tempSprite.physicsBody anchorA:ccp(1,1) anchorB:ccp(600,0) restLength:0.f stiffness:20000.f damping:60.f];

Comment: Don't use `connectedSpringJointWithBodyA` use `connectedDistanceJointWithBodyA`.

Comment: i used the distance joint, but when arrow starts moving, the fire-body moves around the arrow keeping the arrow-front as center and radius the string between which gets streched sometimes, kept the min and max distance to 0.0, but still the same problem..

[CCPhysicsJoint connectedDistanceJointWithBodyA:explosion.physicsBody bodyB:tempSprite.physicsBody anchorA:ccp(0.5,0.5) anchorB:ccp(600,0) minDistance:0.0 maxDistance:0.0];